# Is encrypting twice good or bad?

Tags: security, encryption

A few month ago I was reading somewhere that if you re-encrypt an encrypted message, it does not improve its security and it evens makes the cipher less secure. But as I search now, I cannot find any specific article regarding this case. It would be great if you let me know, and it would be awesome it you give me a reference so I can read about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: encrypting is better than plain text, but where possible, use a one way hash.

Comment: @Radu Enigma, a perfectly good encryption scheme for its time (before WW2) was involutive. You could literally not do worse than encrypting an even number of times with the same key (but hopefully you would notice).

Comment: Downvoted, not a development question, search [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) instead. If you cannot find an answer, they seem to have got an excellent team of cryptographers ready.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer really depends on the encryption being used.

If you [rot-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) your plaintext twice, you get the plaintext back.

If you apply [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) twice with different keys, you get the effect of a larger keyspace for an attacker to search.  [See reference at RSA.](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2230)

The difference is whether the encryption function forms an algebraic group under functional composition.  That is the same as saying the difference depends on whether, for an encryption function **F()** and keys *Ki* applied to a message *m*, does F( *K1*, F( *K2*, *m*)) == F( *K3*, *m* ) for some *K3*?

Comment: Yes that is true, but we know that we do not use rot-13 for encryption, that would be used for puzzles. Anyhow, so if your equation becomes true, then it is meaningless to encrypt two times, right?

Comment: @Erfan - rot-13 is just an example.  Imagine rot-*k*.  Then if you apply rot-5 and rot-8, you have really applied rot-13.  But yes, if the equation is true, then it is useless to encrypt twice.  That is why it's significant that the reference cited at RSA determined that DES is not a group, i.e., does not satisfy that equation.

Comment: As CodeInChaos pointed out about RSA, it does satisfy the equation and therefore no benefit comes from applying it doubly.

Comment: I see, now it makes much more sense to me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: would it be the same for hashing also? I mean the idea of security in double hashing.

Comment: That depends on whether the "one-way" hash functions ultimately turn out to be one-way, or whether there is a mathematical way to "reverse" them.  AFAIK, the answer to that is not known.  In practical terms, either the hash functions provide zero security to begin with, or combining them does increase the security of the typical examples.  Take the design of SHA-*, which has multiple rounds using a key-scheduling function.  Multiple applications has the effect of "implementing more rounds" although using the same key schedule.

Answer (score 4):

### For symmetric block ciphers:

There are two different cases: Encryption using the same key, and encryption using two independent keys.

Using different keys makes the encryption at least as strong as the stronger of the encryptions you use. In practice likely stronger than the stronger, but that's not guaranteed.

Using the same key is more problematic. But in practice it'll likely increase security over the individual cipher.

The main disadvantage of double encryption is that it's twice as slow.

### For RSA

Using plain, paddingless RSA, double encrypting with the same key wouldn't increase security at all, since composing RSA encryption results in a single RSA encryption with a combined key.

But that's not relevant in practice, since you don't typically encrypt data directly with RSA, and you almost always use padding.

---

But a lot depends on what you're doing. For example when hashing, it's very important how the hashes are combined, and when you combine them in the wrong way, you might end up weakening your scheme significantly.

Comment: @Radu Encryption algorithms are almost always designed to have high performance. Deliberate slowdown is only done for very few applications, such as password hashing. But that's no encryption in the first place. So can you please point out where it's beneficial for encryption/decryption to be slow?

Comment: @Radu - That is not necessarily true.  Suppose the encryption function F() defines a group under functional composition.  Then, applying the function twice (even using two different keys) results in output that can be decrypted in the same time as if the function had been applied once.  The difference is that the decryption key is a third key, not used during the encryption.  That is, if *m* is the message, F(*k2*, F( *k1*, m )) == F( *k3*, m), when F() under functional composition defines an algebraic group.

Comment: @Radu A longer key makes the work for a brute-force attacker exponentially harder, slower encryption only linearly. It's obvious which choice is superior. The real performance trade-off is performance vs. resistance against cryptoanalysis. The more rounds an algorithm has, the harder it is to cryptoanalyze. That it gets slower is an undesirable side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Say you had a one-time pad and an xor function . . .

But seriously, it does not really make any difference. Personally, I feel that ciphers should be designed to be effective at one application, because in my experience often repeated applications amplify some artefacts that reduce the entropy of the ciphertext. It's kind of like destructive interference, where a large number of signals line up....that does seem to happen sometimes with repeating the same cipher -- though the effect is (for good ciphers) much less when you use different keys than if you use the same key. But it still makes me uneasy.

I believe the only reason to do it is to chain the plain/ciphertext in both directions so that errors are propagated and persist indicating that the message has been tampered with.

Comment: "because in my experience often repeated applications amplify some artefacts that reduce the entropy of the ciphertext." Can you give an example with a non trivial cipher, say DES, any AES finalist,...