# Encrypt a string twice... Good, Bad or Ugly?

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael

I'm working on an encryption class that is using Rijndael algorithm (C#, ASP.Net 4.5), and out of curiosity I was wondering how beneficial would it be to encrypt the string twice. I mean Encrypt the string with a key and then Encrypt the resulting encryption with another key?

Does this make it that much more secure (I know nothing is ever secure and there could be other holes in my software that could be used to exploit)? Is it worth the CPU overhead (not sure how heavy this is but I can't imagine it would light)?

I was looking for some suggestions online but was not able to find any. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the encryption is "secure" I do not see how there could be an added benefit except, perhaps, eating CPU. Some programs like KeePass will encrypt *millions of times* (1.2M on my box) in order to *burn CPU* .. but 2 seems silly. Also, there was DES, then 3DES, but that was arguably just to patch the weak DES through.

Comment: @user2246674 That's what I'm wondering and this is totally out of curiosity lol, thought it would be a cool little topic to hear from the experts here :)

Comment: My take on it: Rijndael/AES is "secure". Then it's just a matter of using it securely: e.g. using the [correct mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/967/aes-in-ecb-mode-weakness) and safeguarding the keys. While I accept KeePass's burning approach for its problem domain (potentially weak master passwords), it really sounds sketchy to encrypt twice in hopes that it will make the encryption "more secure".

Comment: @hjavaher Maybe this link can help
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/is-multiple-encryption-a-good-idea
and going even further with cascading encryption idea
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/is-truecrypts-multiple-cascading-encryption-safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a couple of questions that may be of use to you:

- [Is there any benefit to encrypting twice using pgp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771315/is-there-any-benefit-to-encrypting-twice-using-pgp)
- [Is encrypting twice good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345068/is-encrypting-twice-good-or-bad)
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/779/hashing-or-encrypting-twice-to-increase-security
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/is-it-safer-to-encrypt-twice-with-rsa
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/does-encrypting-twice-using-the-same-block-cipher-produce-a-security-weakness

General idea seems to be this point:

> Well, think about it this way. If breaking one encryption with brute
>   force will take longer than the lifetime of the universe, are you any
>   safer with an encryption scheme that will take twice the lifetime of
>   the universe? No. The first encryption cannot be broken. Adding a
>   second encryption just adds computation overhead with no real benefit. - mikeazo

I would advise asking this question in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/, they may give you more detailed information on the topic.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that Stack Exchange had a Crypto site. I will but my initial feeling was the above anyways so I think I got my answer.

Comment: Nit: The "general idea" assumes that the key cannot be brute-forced (which is a valid assumption with *strong keys*) - but something like KeePass can really benefit from the burn. It's not that the makes the encryption stronger, but it protects in cases of brute-force attacks against *keys in a limited ("weak") key-space*. My master key is much less secure (on the order of only about "60 bits" .. *maybe*) than the keys it is guarding. Maybe I should fix that - or just rely on the burn. *Shrug*.

Comment: See also: http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/02/multiple-encryption.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple rule in cryptography.  All the security should be in the key.  Based on that there should be no additional security in encrypting twice because all your security should be in the choice and storage of your key.

Now that being said... you could get some additional security if you make wrong choices.  For example say you encrypt the first time with ECB mode (Electronic Code book), because of the way that mode works (by encrypting each block of your plaintext separately), you could get extra security by encrypting a second time in a more secure mode (CBC or CTR).  But... you could just as well encrypt in CBC mode the first time around.

You could encrypt the first time with an insecure algorithm (such as DES) and encrypt a second time with a much better algorithm (such as AES).

But these situations are hypothetical and would require you to intentionally make mistakes or be extremely negligent.  If you use AES (Rijandael) twice in a secure mode like CTR or CBC then you will not get any additional security from encrypting twice so long as your key is stored securly and selected in a secure manner.